# How to draw or mark an area without having any data of that area?

Tags: data, carto

I'm doing some market research to start a business in Amsterdam. The City consists of 8 city area's which I'd like to map in my map as one of the layers and then add data to it.

I already called to City Hall to see if they had the data readily available for importing into a GIS solution but unfortunately they don't.

The best I could do was find a map with an overview of the city parts and neighbourhoods.

Does anyone have an idea or tip on how to best go about this?
I'm making my map in CartoDB. I'm open to solutions using Mapbox.

I have no programming skills so please bear with me.

Comment: Have you tried open street map?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you want data depicting the boundaries of those 8 city areas? OR do you want data depicting roads, buildings, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can add and edit geometries (points/markers, lines or polygons) in CartoDB. [Here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/adding_geometries/) you have a step by step tutorial about how to do it. But I also recommend you to look for that data in other places besides the City Hall.

Answer (score -1):

Relevant link (sorry, can't comment at the moment):
https://maps.amsterdam.nl/?LANG=en